# Datatables.net and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Is it possible, without integration into the plugin code, to change datatables rows to divs and rows used by twitter bootstrap ? So they would wrap nicely on small screen devices ?

Comment: Explained solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775316/how-to-use-jquery-datatable-net-with-asp-net-4-razor-and-twitter-bootstrap/16775317#16775317).