# How to use JQuery Datatable.net with ASP.Net 4 Razor and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, razor, datatables

I want to use the jQuery Datatable with ASP.net MVC and Twitter bootstrap.

Does anyone have already done this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be an old post but I just wanted to add how I got things set up. It seems to be easier than how codea did it above.

1) In your view, simply create your table like normal (with a @foreach or some such thing) and give it an ID of `jqueryTable`. Then download the following 3 files and put them in the `~/Scripts/` and the `~/Content/` folders:

[dataTables.bootstrap.css](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css)

[jquery.dataTables.js](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js)

[dataTables.bootstrap.js](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js)

Now add those files to your BundleConfig.cs file using the following code:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/datatables").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js",
    "~/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/datatables").Include(
    "~/Content/dataTables.bootstrap.css"));
```

Finally, add the following to the view where you created your table (note that the JS file order matters!):

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/datatables")

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/datatables")

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        /* Table initialization */
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#jqueryTable').dataTable();
        });

    </script>
}
```

The JS code above simply finds your table (with an ID of `jqueryTable`) and initializes the datatables JS on it. Also, for this to work, the `~/bundles/jquery` will need to be included in your `_Layout.cshtml` file (which it should be by default).

Answer (score 1):

I have mainly inspired my solution from there, thanks to the author: http://www.datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2

What you have to do is to put the javascipt given in the post into a js file and your CSS into the tables.less file (this is assuming you are using less for your css, if you dont just drop the CSS into your bootstrap.css file) :

**jquery.dataTables.twitterbootstrap.js**

```
/* Set the defaults for DataTables initialisation */
$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
"sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
"sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
"oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
}
});

/* Default class modification */
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
    "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
});


/* API method to get paging information */
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function (oSettings) {
    return {
        "iStart": oSettings._iDisplayStart,
        "iEnd": oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
        "iLength": oSettings._iDisplayLength,
        "iTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
        "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
        "iPage": oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
            0 : Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength),
        "iTotalPages": oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
            0 : Math.ceil(oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength)
    };
};


/* Bootstrap style pagination control */
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination, {
    "bootstrap": {
        "fnInit": function (oSettings, nPaging, fnDraw) {
            var oLang = oSettings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
            var fnClickHandler = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, e.data.action)) {
                    fnDraw(oSettings);
                }
            };

            $(nPaging).addClass('pagination').append(
                '<ul>' +
                    '<li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">&larr; ' + oLang.sPrevious + '</a></li>' +
                    '<li class="next disabled"><a href="#">' + oLang.sNext + ' &rarr; </a></li>' +
                '</ul>'
            );
            var els = $('a', nPaging);
            $(els[0]).bind('click.DT', { action: "previous" }, fnClickHandler);
            $(els[1]).bind('click.DT', { action: "next" }, fnClickHandler);
        },

        "fnUpdate": function (oSettings, fnDraw) {
            var iListLength = 5;
            var oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();
            var an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
            var i, ien, j, sClass, iStart, iEnd, iHalf = Math.floor(iListLength / 2);

            if (oPaging.iTotalPages < iListLength) {
                iStart = 1;
                iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
            }
            else if (oPaging.iPage <= iHalf) {
                iStart = 1;
                iEnd = iListLength;
            } else if (oPaging.iPage >= (oPaging.iTotalPages - iHalf)) {
                iStart = oPaging.iTotalPages - iListLength + 1;
                iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
            } else {
                iStart = oPaging.iPage - iHalf + 1;
                iEnd = iStart + iListLength - 1;
            }

            for (i = 0, ien = an.length; i < ien; i++) {
                // Remove the middle elements
                $('li:gt(0)', an[i]).filter(':not(:last)').remove();

                // Add the new list items and their event handlers
                for (j = iStart; j <= iEnd; j++) {
                    sClass = (j == oPaging.iPage + 1) ? 'class="active"' : '';
                    $('<li ' + sClass + '><a href="#">' + j + '</a></li>')
                        .insertBefore($('li:last', an[i])[0])
                        .bind('click', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            oSettings._iDisplayStart = (parseInt($('a', this).text(), 10) - 1) * oPaging.iLength;
                            fnDraw(oSettings);
                        });
                }

                // Add / remove disabled classes from the static elements
                if (oPaging.iPage === 0) {
                    $('li:first', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                } else {
                    $('li:first', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                }

                if (oPaging.iPage === oPaging.iTotalPages - 1 || oPaging.iTotalPages === 0) {
                    $('li:last', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                } else {
                    $('li:last', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});


/*
* TableTools Bootstrap compatibility
* Required TableTools 2.1+
*/
if ($.fn.DataTable.TableTools) {
    // Set the classes that TableTools uses to something suitable for Bootstrap
    $.extend(true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
        "container": "DTTT btn-group",
        "buttons": {
            "normal": "btn",
            "disabled": "disabled"
        },
        "collection": {
            "container": "DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu",
            "buttons": {
                "normal": "",
                "disabled": "disabled"
            }
        },
        "print": {
            "info": "DTTT_print_info modal"
        },
        "select": {
            "row": "active"
        }
    });

    // Have the collection use a bootstrap compatible dropdown
    $.extend(true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.DEFAULTS.oTags, {
        "collection": {
            "container": "ul",
            "button": "li",
            "liner": "a"
        }
    });
}
```

**CSS to insert into tables.less OR into bootstrap.css**

```
table.table thead .sorting,
table.table thead .sorting_asc,
table.table thead .sorting_desc,
table.table thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
table.table thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
    cursor: pointer;
    *cursor: hand;
}

table.table thead .sorting { background: url('@{imagesPath}sort_both.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.table thead .sorting_asc { background: url('@{imagesPath}sort_asc.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.table thead .sorting_desc { background: url('@{imagesPath}sort_desc.png') no-repeat center right; }

table.table thead .sorting_asc_disabled { background: url('@{imagesPath}sort_asc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.table thead .sorting_desc_disabled { background: url('@{imagesPath}sort_desc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }
```

**Then you can build your table in your ASP.net razor page .cshtml like this**

```
@model IEnumerable<Data>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Datatable example";
}


<h2  class="text-info">Datatable Example</h2>

<table   cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="jqueryTable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="text-info">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var object in Model)
        { 
            <tr >
                <td style="min-width: 30px">
                    @object.ID
                </td>
                <td style="min-width: 140px">
                    @object.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @object.Value
                </td>
            </tr>                   
        }
    </tbody>

</table>

@section scripts
{    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery.dataTables.twitterbootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        /* Table initialisation */
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#jqueryTable').dataTable({
                "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                 "aaSorting": [ ],
                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                "iDisplayLength": 5,
                "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ values per page"
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

Hope this helps !